# EXCEL Smallest value with specific value in adjacent cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003

What I want is fairly simple I need a formula which will give me the smallest value with a given string in the cell next to it.

```
a   1
f   5
m   4
s   7
f   3
a   3
```

So for "a" it would give me 1 because 1<3 and for "f" it would give me 3 because 3<5

I'm working with Excel 2003

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **Array formula** :

=MIN(IF(A1:A10="f",B1:B10))

Array formulas must be entered with **CNTRL-SHFT-ENTER** rather than just the **ENTER** key